# How to Add Scale Parameter

Tags: python, caffe

I have the following caffe Layer I want to add:

```
layer {
  name: "s"
  type: "Scale"
  bottom: "o"
  top: "o"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  scale_param {
    filler {
      value: 1    }
    bias_term: true
    bias_filler {
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I need to create this with Python. How do I do this?

```
caffeNet.tops[gScaleName] = L.Scale(caffeNet.tops[gConvName],
                                        param=[dict(lr_mult=0, decay_mult=0), dict(lr_mult=1, decay_mult=0)],
                                        scale_param=[dict(bias_term=True), dict(bias_filler=dict(value=0)), dict(filler=dict(value=0))]
                                        )
```

I try this and it gives an error saying `ScaleParameter has no attribute add`. How do I add it?

Comment: why are you using Scale layer here? you are only allowing for bias. Use Bias layer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
caffeNet.tops[gScaleName] = L.Scale(caffeNet.tops[gConvName],
                                    param=[{'lr_mut': 0, 'decay_mult': 0},
                                           {'lr_mult': 1, 'decay_mult': 0}],
                                    scale_param={'filler': {'value': 1},
                                                 'bias_term': True,
                                                 'bias_filler': {'value': 1})
```

Note that `scale_param` is a `dict` and not a `list` of `dict`s.
If you look carefully at [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L413) you'll notice that while `scale_param` is `optional`:

```
optional ScaleParameter scale_param = 142;
```

Meaning there can be at most one value for `scale_param` in each `layer`. When it comes to `param` it is defined as `repeated`:

```
repeated ParamSpec param = 6;
```

Meaning there can be an array/list of `param`s in each layer.

---

BTW,
The way you define your `Scale` layer you fix the scale to 1 and set the learning rate to zero meaning you only learn the bias in this layer.
Why don't you use a [`"Bias"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/bias.html) layer and skip the redundant scale?

Comment: thats a great point. I am referencing another model, shall look into it